# argparse allowing arbitrary flags

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way to allow `argparse` to accept arbitrary flags?

For example, I have a wrapper over `git push` called `gitter`

I would prefer to not have to specify all the flags available to `git push` as there are many.

However, I still want to be able to do something like

```
gitter --all --no-verify
```

Is there a way for `argparse` to take arbitrary flags and have those flags be passed onto `git push`?

If I do `gitter --fake-flag`, I immediately get an error without the chance of parsing out the flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `parse_known_args` to leave unrecognized flags in a list.

```
p = ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("--foo")
args, remaining = p.parse_known_args("--foo 5 --bar --baz".split())

# args.foo == 5
# remaining = ["--bar", "--baz"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am guessing that I should replace '"--foo 5 --bar --baz".split()' with my actual flags that I can some how get from the ArgumentParser()?

Comment: Yes. `parse_known_args` doesn't require you to define *any* flags; anything on the command line that isn't defined is simply put (in order) in the second element of the tuple returned by `parse_known_args`. Flags that are recognized are parsed, removed, and used to set attributes of the first element.

Comment: Thanks again for getting back to me. Would you happen to know how to generate `"--foo 5 --bar --baz".split()` using `ArgumentParser()`? After fiddling around with it, I tried `parse_args()` but this returns a `namespace` object which can't be converted into a list object.

Comment: Both `parse_args` and `parse_known_args` just take a list of words (by default, `sys.argv[1:]`) as an argument. I use `split` as a quick-n-dirty method to generate a list from a string.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a bash script for gitter instead of Python?  Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
git push --alwaysArg "$@"
```

When run:

```
gitter --all --no-verify
```

The resulting command will be:

```
git push --alwaysArg --all --no-verify
```